# what is the rtp payload value for amr-nb codec?

Tags: sip, rtp, codec, amr

I found Rtp payload values for PCMU=0 and G729=18 etc.But I cant find value for AMR.I search in this link [Rtp_parameters](https://www.iana.org/assignments/rtp-parameters/rtp-parameters.xm)

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific [fixed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTP_audio_video_profile) value reserved for AMR, values for dynamic assignment range are to be used.

[RFC 3551](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3551):

> This profile reserves payload type numbers in the range 96-127 exclusively for dynamic assignment.  Applications SHOULD first use values in this range for dynamic payload types.

Example from [RFC 4867](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4867):

```
m=audio 49120 RTP/AVP 97 98 99
a=rtpmap:97 AMR/8000/1
a=fmtp:97 mode-set=0,2,5,7; mode-change-period=2; \
  mode-change-capability=2; mode-change-neighbor=1
a=rtpmap:98 AMR/8000/1
a=fmtp:98 mode-set=0,2,3,6; mode-change-period=2; \
  mode-change-capability=2; mode-change-neighbor=1
a=rtpmap:99 AMR/8000/1
a=fmtp:99 mode-set=0,2,3,4; mode-change-period=2; \
  mode-change-capability=2; mode-change-neighbor=1
a=maxptime:20
```